# I dont understand why my SQL table is not being created

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im trying to create a new SQLite table, and I followed the instructions to the latter, but I keep reciving the error

```
no such table: USERS_TABLE (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)
```

As you can see, I created a constuactor and the line with the `CREATE TABLE` statement. I wrote the exact same lines on the different projects and they worked just fine. Maybe you can help me find the problem?

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String ID = "ID";//Saves the ID column name.
    public static final String USERS_TABLE = "USERS_TABLE";
    public static final String COLUMN_UNAME = "COLUMN_UNAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_UPASS = "COLUMN_UPASS";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name) {
        super(context, name, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + USERS_TABLE + " (" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_UNAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_UPASS + " INT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public void addOneU(UserModel userModel) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_UNAME, userModel.getuName());
        cv.put(COLUMN_UPASS, userModel.getuPass());

        db.insert(USERS_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public List<UserModel> getAllUsers(){
        List<UserModel> returnL = new ArrayList<>();

        String qString = "SELECT * FROM " + USERS_TABLE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(qString, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int userID = cursor.getInt(0);
                String userN = cursor.getString(1);
                int userPass = cursor.getInt(2);

                UserModel userModel = new UserModel(userN, userPass, userID);
                returnL.add(userModel);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }    
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return returnL;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Is there a chance you created this table in your application, but then made changes to it afterwards? Did you try uninstalling your application and working with a fresh install?

Comment: whtat do you mean by configurations? this is the DB as it curently is. I will try to uninstall

Comment: It worked! thank you so much! 
Can I aprove your comment somehow?

Comment: @tomerpacific: You may want to convert your comment to an answer so that the OP can accept it.

Comment: @KfirArnesty - I added an answer. Please mark it and upvote it as it helped your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, when you create a SQLite DB in your application and run it, but then make changes to it and try to run the application again, you will get the error you have written.

In order to amend the situation, you need to completely uninstall the application and perform a fresh installation.